# Getting access is denied for cmd command using php function

Tags: php, iis, cmd, exec, system

I am running PHP under IIS 6.

When I use any PHP function to run cmd commands (like `exec()` or `system()`), it always shows "Access is denied".

Even commands like `ipconfig` are showing same "access is denied" error. I have given all the permission to my project folder but it did not work.

Please let me know anyone the cause of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute some command using `exec`, that command will be executed with the user account that is running IIS (which tipically is `IUSR_«machine-name»` on IIS 6), so your project's permissions don't have nothing to do with this.

What you need to do is to chance the permissions of the file `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` and add permissions for `IUSR_«machine-name»`.

Besides this, you'll probably need to use CACLS to change the access control list. Replace `IUSR_MachineName` on the following command for the user executing PHP and then execute this command:

```
CACLS c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /E /G IUSR_MachineName:F
```

If you get an error and can't change the ACL, your last resource is to execute the following command first:

```
takeown /F c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

You also might need to set the correct permissions and ACL for the commands you're trying to execute (for eg `C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe`)

**Note**: Do this with caution though. If you have some vulnerability that allows your users to execute commands, it can have nasty consequences.

Comment: Is the error `Access is denied`? What is the command that you're trying to execute? Do you have any additional information in the Event Viewer?

Comment: yes, error id "Access is denied" and I have to use 2>&1 to show error.
I was using "schtasks" to run scheduler using php but after searching I found out, no any command is working using php function, even "ipconfig" command showing "Access is denied".

Comment: @Ashok check the updated answer. You most likely need to execute the `cacls` command. I've set up a system to simulate your situation and it worked.