# How to use cron job on localhost in Windows with Laravel 5

Tags: php, batch-file, laravel, cron

I found this post here : [Run Cron Job on PHP Script, on localhost in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035090/run-cron-job-on-php-script-on-localhost-in-windows) which is working perfectly. Instead of a PHP file I want to run an URL instead, like http://localhost/test-cron-job

I tried to simply change this line here:

```
"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" -f "C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Work\cronjob\my_script.php"
```

to this:

```
"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" -f "http://localhost/test-cron-job"
```

But it is not working at all. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Edit for grammar, wording

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `php.exe` is supposed to execute a PHP file. When you point it to a URL it doesn't know what to do.

What you need is something like [curl for Windows](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and then you can make a HTTP request:

```
curl http://localhost/test-cron-job
```

Comment: Hello there, I tried what you were asking me. But when I put this curl "http://localhost/test-cron-job" in my script.bat, nothing happen. But, if I go to the command prompt as an Administrator and then I type curl "http://localhost/test-cron-job", this is executing perfectly. What is wrong? Did I miss something?

Comment: @MatthieuBoisjoli Most likely, the user from your webserver doesn't have permissions to execute the `curl` executable. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29683406/908174) to know how to set permissions in windows files.