# PHP run exec() command

Tags: php, iis

I have the code below to test, I can execute `exec()` commands on my server but it is failing with the error below:

```
<?php
echo exec('C:\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java 2>&1', $output, $return);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($output);
echo "<br>";
echo $return;
?>
```

Error that I am getting after running the above code.

```
Access is denied.
array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "Access is denied." } 
1

IIS version is : 7.5
Windows Version is : Windows Server 2008 R2
```

I have tried to follow threads online in adding and changing permission but it is still not working. I have taken ownership of the cmd.exe file and added everyone to execute the file.

Comment: looks like a user permission issue

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29683406/1935500

Comment: @AziSaleh, I have tried it but there is no user like IUSR_MachineName on my system. I only have IUSR as a group and I have granted read and write permission that that user.